# Apache Ignite: Whether or not it is possible to do these things?

Tags: sql, ignite

I am doing a POC to decide if Apache Ignite can do these things.

I have 3 important use cases:

1. Insert data into SQL. I know it does, but I want this with point 2 below.
2. Have a continuous query for a specific SQL select listen to the update
   For example: Let's say I would like to have this listener run only for a 
   query like:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE_1 p1 
   inner join TABLE_2 p2 
   on (p1.id =  p2.id)
   ```

   Is it possible?
3. Occasionally be able to run a SELECT from external clients. I know it does but I want this with point 2 above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do both selects and updates using SQL. Please refer to the documentation for all the details: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/

However, continuous queries are not SQL based. It's basically a listener that gets notified about updates in a cache. You can optionally have a remote filter on server side, but that's a piece of Java code, not a SQL query. More info here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries